# Python: Add conditional column in dataframe - if date lies in any of the multiple periods defined in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, data-science

**I have a df1:**

[image: df1]

**I have another df2:**

[image: df2]

I want to add another column in df1 Flag:

- 1 if Timestamp for that Job lies in any of the Time period defined in df2 against that job (in any of the 4 Jobnames in df2).
- 0 otherwise.

I tried to be as clear as possible.

I have done it iterating over the df1 rows using iterrows, but we all know that is not the right/efficient way.

***I'm looking for a vectorized operation to achieve the same!!***

Comment: Welcome to S/O. Please post a minimally reproducible code example so we can help you. Furthermore, please don't include a picture of the data. Just create a minimal example of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *TimeStamp*, *StartTime* and *EndTime* columns in your DataFrames
are of *datetime* type (not *string*).

First reformat *df2* into *df3* the following way:

```
df3 = df2.set_index(['Key', 'StartTime', 'EndTime']).stack()\
    .replace('', np.nan).dropna().reset_index(level=[0,3], drop=True)\
    .rename('JobName').reset_index()
```

For my sample data (first few rows of your *df2*) the result is:

```
            StartTime             EndTime JobName
0 2019-04-20 12:30:00 2019-04-20 13:20:00       A
1 2019-04-20 12:30:00 2019-04-20 13:20:00       S
2 2019-04-16 12:30:00 2019-04-21 13:20:00       B
3 2019-04-17 12:30:00 2019-04-22 13:20:00       C
4 2019-04-17 12:30:00 2019-04-22 13:20:00       A
5 2019-04-17 12:30:00 2019-04-22 13:20:00       G
```

Then define the following function, returning the *Flag* value for
the current *row* in *df1*:

```
def getFlag(row):
    return 1 if any(df3.JobName.eq(row.JobName) & df3.StartTime.le(row.TimeStamp)
        & df3.EndTime.ge(row.TimeStamp)) else 0
```

And the last step is to apply this function and save the result in a new column:

```
df1['Flag'] = df1.apply(getFlag, axis=1)
```